# Adding rectangle to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, paint

So I've made a **`Rectangle`**, but I want to show it in the panel, but I have no idea how, I've tried many things, but clearly not enough. And I would appreciate help on this one. I'm very new so please give me a step by step answer or something alike.

Here's the code which includes the `Rectangle`

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestProjectDialog extends JPanel{

    static String name;
    public Rectangle  r;


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
        super.paintComponent(g);
         r = new Rectangle(430,50,250,400);
         g.setColor(jpp.bodyColour);
        g.fillRect((int)r.getX(),(int)r.getY(),(int)r.getHeight(),(int)r.getWidth());

    }

    TestProjectJPanel jpp = new TestProjectJPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args){



    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Just about to draw a REALLY GOOD 2D car \n just need input please.");

     name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Imagine a car, what is it's name?");
    if(name == null || (name != null && ("".equals(name))))   
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input/pressed cancel, closing program.");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ah okay, so it's name is " + name); 

    JFrame f = new JFrame(name);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TestProjectJPanel jpp = new TestProjectJPanel();


    jpp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    f.setSize(1440,900);
    f.add(jpp.panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.add(jpp.b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

And the code which has the **`panel`** itself

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class TestProjectJPanel extends JFrame {


    public JButton b;
    public Color color = (Color.WHITE);
    public JPanel panel;
    public Color bodyColour;
    public Color doorColour;
    public Color wheelColour;


    public TestProjectJPanel(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);

        // bodyColour button
        b = new JButton("Choose a colour for the body of the car");
        b.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                        bodyColour = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Pick the colour", bodyColour);
                        if(bodyColour==null) 
                            bodyColour = (Color.BLACK);


                    }
                }
                );

    }

        }
```

So basically, I want to add the `Rectangle` onto the `panel`, but **i have no idea how.** I'm fairly new at programming so make the answer easy for a beginner to read.

EDIT: also what I want this program to do, is to start off with a prompt asking for a name, which I store in the String name and set it as the title, then I want a `Panel` to appear and you can choose the colour of the `Rectangle` using the **`JColorChooser`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong panel. That's all.
Change `f.add(jpp.panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` to `f.add(new TestProjectDialog(), BorderLayout.CENTER);` and you should be good.

HTH, Jan